# Firebase cloud messaging broadcast is determine by bundle ID or the firebase project (GoogleService-Info.plist)

Tags: ios, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have 2 firebase projects (with same bundle id).

If I use the firebase console cloud messaging to broadcast message (with target user segment of iOS and bundle id of com.test.xxx), will the users of both projects (different GoogleService-Info.plist) receive the notification?

Question: Is the receiver determine by the bundle ID (iOS) or the GoogleService-Info.plist of the app?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The FCM token is based on Firebase Project ID, Device token, Bundle ID and a host of other details. So incase you are broadcasting a message using the Cloud Messaging API, it will only be sent to the Apps containing the GoogleService-Info.plist from that particular project and not to all apps with the same bundle id.

Comment: yes i've just tested with a new project and only Apps containing the GoogleService-Info.plist from that particular project and not to all apps with the same bundle id. However, in the old project, i wonder why it doesn't behave this way.